# How to use getClass() with a class that has a generic in java?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I need to pass `Class<TableEditInfo<Generic Type>>` to a method to create an array of that generic type, but I am not sure how to get TableEditInfo.class with a generic. I have tried this:

```
TableEditInfo<Integer> editInfo = new TableEditInfo<Integer>(someData);
c.add(editInfo.getClass(), editInfo)
```

but it shows me Unchecked cast: `'java.lang.Class<capture<? extends app.mainWindow.edit.TableEditInfo>>' to 'java.lang.Class<app.mainWindow.edit.TableEditInfo<java.lang.Integer>>'`. It works but I don't know if this code is correct or is it not a good practise to do that. If its bad, how do I do it properly?

c is other class object that stores the `TableEditInfo<T>` array

add looks like that:

```
public void add(Class<TableEditInfo<T>> type, TableEditInfo<T> editInfo){
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    TableEditInfo<T>[] arr = (TableEditInfo<T>[]) Array.newInstance(type,1);
    arr[0] = editInfo;

    stack.push(arr);
```

}

basically it makes a singleton array, because I just need it for some specific reason.

Comment: What is "c" here?

Comment: c is other class object that stores the TableEditInfo<T> array.

Comment: What's the signature of the `add` method then?

Comment: @HenryTwist It takes the Class<TableEditInfo<Type>> and TableEditInfo<Type> to create a singleton array from it (I just need it for some reason), but I don't know if the way I passed Class<TableEditInfo<Type>> is correct (because I make a generic array so I suppose I need to do it this way with Class<T> clazz =  Array.newInstance(clazz, size)).

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include it? You haven't ever mentioned what `Type` is. Is it a generic of the `add` method?

Comment: @HenryTwist I have edited my question, I hope its all clear now, I should have thought about giving more info about what specific words mean in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `editInfo.getClass()` has type `Class<? extends TableEditInfo>`. The `? extends` is because the object's actual runtime class could be a subclass of `TableEditInfo`, and the lack of `<T>` is because there aren't really `Class` objects representing `TableEditInfo<Integer>` or `TableEditInfo<String>`, etc. -- there is only one `Class` instance at runtime representing the class `TableEditInfo`.

In any case, the simplest solution is to just remove the `type` parameter, which is useless. At runtime, the passed argument will always be the same -- it will point to the single `Class` instance representing the class `TableEditInfo`, namely, `TableEditInfo.class`.

You can replace `Array.newInstance(type,1)` with either `new TableEditInfo[1]` or `new TableEditInfo<?>[1]`. Both of those are legal. (The former can be assigned to `TableEditInfo<T>[]` directly with an unchecked conversion warning. The latter needs a cast to be assigned to `TableEditInfo<T>[]`, which will cause an unchecked cast warning.)